# Where can I load a view that needs to know the contents of an Ivar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextview, viewwillappear

I am using a UIScrollView to create the illusion of lined paper behind my UITextView (I have to use a separate UIScrollView so I can have margins). In order to draw the paper with the correct number of lines, I need to pass it the `contentSize.height` of the UITextView.

Here is what happens at the moment:

1. the user selects a note from a table in the parent view controller.
2. the parent view controller sets the textview.text property so my UITextView will know what text to show.

If I set up my UIScrollView in `viewWillAppear`, it won't work because textView.text has not been set yet, so the textView.contentSize.height is zero. But if I set it up in `viewDidAppear`, although it works, the lines appear a moment after the text.

What is the right way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try to set the property before pushing the child view controller.

I assume that your code is something like in the parent view controller :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIViewController* childViewController = ...
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childViewController animated:YES];
    childViewController.text = ...
    [childViewController release];
}
```

Maybe simply try

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIViewController* childViewController = ...
    childViewController.text = ...
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childViewController animated:YES];
    [childViewController release];
}
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but if do that, the text turns up blank! Maybe I should try setting a separate text property, and then only assigning the actual textview.text from that in viewWillAppear... back in a minute...

Comment: It's probably that the view is not loaded when you call the `UITextView`. You can try to overwrite the getter of the textView and check if the view is loaded with `isViewLoaded`. If it's not loaded, simply do it!

Comment: Just tried using a different property... I can't seem to set properties until after I've pushed the child view controller onto the stack.

Comment: How can it be? If the view is loaded, the IBOutlets are set. Maybe if you show me more code : do you place the textView manually or with IB?

Comment: My mistake - I set up a property in the child view controller, but didn't set it from the parent view controller. It works now. So I can set my own properties before pushing the view controller, but I can't set parameters of subviews I have as properties. Good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize all of your views in `-viewDidLoad`...
Indeed before the moment when `-viewDidLoad` has been called, your view has not been fully loaded.

If you need to pass data between controllers, you could define a property in one of your controllers and set its value. The other controller would read that property when required.

Specifically, in -`viewDidLoad` you can use the value stored in the property to initialize your UI item.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a simple `NSString *noteText` ivar on the child view controller, and make it a propery like `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *noteText` and synthesize it. Then as gcamp suggests do something like:

```
YourChildController *childVC = ...
child.noteText = @"your selected note text here";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childVC animated:YES];
[childVC release];
```

Then in YourChildController viewDidLoad:

```
myTextView.text = noteText;
[myTextView sizeToFit]; // not sure if you need to do this or not

// now you can setup your background scroll view as needed
```

If that doesn't work you can try to setup your scrollview in your viewWillAppear: method.